# Camel Compatibility issues

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel

I am using the following camel packages in my Maven project:

camel-core
camel-jms
camel-jaxb
camel-quartz
camel-bindy
camel-ftp

And when all these are using version 2.8.0 my server starts up fine and the app works ok. But if I update the camel version to anything higher like 2.10.0 then I get the following exception on startup and not sure which of these is causing this issue:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConverterLoaderException: Failed to load type converters because of: Cannot find any type converter classes from the following packages: [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote]
```

Any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe another library of your project is using a different version of camel.

You can check the camel dependency tree of your project with this maven command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=camel-core
```

In verbose mode, the dependency tree shows dependencies that were omitted for being a duplicate of another, conflicting with another's version and/or scope, and introducing a cycle into the dependency tree.

Here are some reference links:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I had different version of camel libraries. Thanks.